# Reading/writing files: Is "a" faster than "a+" mode?

Tags: python

Based on many people's answer, it looks the only difference between "a" and "a+" mode is that "a+" is not only write/append, but also "read".

From my using file open experience, without "a+" mode, I can do write append with "a" pretty well. Does "a" give me performance improvement if I don't need read for the file at all?

For example:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('line\n');
```

Comment: shouldn't the title be “Python *write* file - ...”?

Comment: the `+` means that the file will be created if it does not exist - this is the same with `w+` vs `w`

Comment: @Daniel not true, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Why would you open it for reading when all you're going to do is write to it? Don't request for something you won't need.

Comment: @JeffMercado that's what I will do but would wonder if there are exceptions causing unexpected failures.. so want to confirm:)

Comment: I don't think it's important at all. It's like asking whether it's faster to use readonly vs read/write memory. It frankly doesn't matter, it only matters what you intend to do with it. I could get on board with a question that asks the difference between append vs write, as that is a more significant difference, but this is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this test on identical text files, the loop using ‘a+’ runs about one one hundredth of a second slower that ‘a’. This difference does not change significantly as the test is repeated and the files continue to grow larger and larger. This would indicate that even though ‘a+’ is very slightly slower, it does not seem to spend any extra time reading the file first.

```
from time import time

start = time ()
with open ('testfile1.txt', 'a') as file :
    for index in range (9999) :
        file.write ('This is a test to see how long this will take.\n')
stop = time ()
first_total = stop - start

start = time ()
with open ('testfile2.txt', 'a+') as file :
    for index in range (9999) :
        file.write ('This is a test to see how long this will take.\n')
stop = time ()
second_total = stop - start

print ('First = ', first_total)
print ('Second = ', second_total)
print ('Differenct = ', second_total - first_total)
```

Comment: It might be better to time this with something like `timeit`. However, I would not expect the time to be significantly different.